# how to write a jasmine test for a setinterval inside a prototype

Tags: jasmine

I want to write a test for my setInterval and test that the alert window has fired with the value 'pulse'. How do I do this? I've tried so many variations on this but can not seem to figure this out. I've provided the code and my spec file. I'm using jasmine 2.0. Any help is appreciated.

countTimer.js

```
function CountTimer(timelength){
  this.timelength = timelength;
  this.running    = false;
}

CountTimer.prototype.start = function(){
  this.running = true;
  setInterval(function () {alert('pulse')}, 2000);
};
CountTimer.prototype.stop = function(){
  this.running = false;
};
```

countTimerSpec.js

```
describe("Timer",function() {
  var myTimer;


  beforeEach(function() {
    myTimer = new CountTimer(25);
  });

...

  it("start should run setInterval 'pulse' every 2 seconds via setInterval", function(){
    myTimer.start();

    //what goes here???

    expect(sut.callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the jasmine clock (it hooks the real clock and allows you to simulate time as you want).

Check the jasmine help - the example there is pretty much exactly what you are trying to do. http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html

Basic steps (in your test):

```
jasmine.clock().install();
myTimer.start();
jasmine.clock().tick(2001); //enough that your interval gets tripped
expect(...)
jasmine.clock().uninstall();
```